Reading and replying to SMS on Linux
I'm using Ubuntu 24.10 and love it! The only thing I miss about Windows 11 is the phoneLink, witch connected my phone and laptop and allowed me to reply and receive and send text mesages for my Android Google Pixel 8. What are the options?
Thanks so much for your knowledge and I look forward to your wisdom.

Try this, you cannot only transfer files, it also enables you to read and reply to messages. It's also available for Android.

You can also read and send SMS from Google's online messages web page. https://messages.google.com/web/welcome

@mook765 FYI We have a canonical question for GSConnect, which I linked.
